# The property is of an interface type ('IFormFile'). If it is a navigation property manually in asp.net core during file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file through View Model and saving that model after some processing, in the database. Both Model(saving model after processing) and file upload are working fine in separately. But when i combine them in a single post request it conflict with the IFormFile property and through this error.

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'ProfileViewModel.ProfileImage' is of an interface type ('IFormFile'). If it is a navigation property manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type, otherwise ignore the property using the NotMappedAttribute or 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Here is my controller code

```
public class ProfileController : Controller 
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public ProfileController(ApplicationDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _context = context;
        _env = env;
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Registration([Bind("Id,Name,ProfileImage")] ProfileViewModel profileViewModel)
    {
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.Name = profileViewModel.Name;
        //loading remaining properties of the model from ViewModel

        //uploading file....
        if (profileViewModel.ProfileImage != null)
        {
            var uploads = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, profileViewModel.ProfileImage.FileName);

            profileViewModel.ProfileImage.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
            profile.ProfileImage = profileViewModel.ProfileImage.FileName;
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(profile);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
         }
        
        return View(profileViewModel);
    }
}
```

ProfileViewModel and Profile model code

```
public class AfghanViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Profile Image")]
    [Required]
    public IFormFile ProfileImage { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    // other attributes are below...........
}
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    ..........
}
```

View file code

```
<form asp-action="Registration" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
     <label asp-for="ProfileImage" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="ProfileImage" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="ProfileImage" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
 .....
</form>
```

File upload works fine, but model not saving and producing above error on this line of code _context.Add(profile);

I tried several things in different answers in this domain, but non of them is working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use entity-types as view-models - for many reasons besides this one (a good sample why is an "Edit User" page that should have two plaintext "password" and "confirm password" fields - but the entity-type for `User` would have a single hashed `PasswordHash` and `PasswordHashSalt` fields - do you see why Entity Models should not be exposed directly to the user now?).

Comment: Instead, define a separate view-model for this view and create a mapping (e.g. using AutoMapper, or by-hand) between the view-model and your entity type.

Comment: I did not understand your whole idea. Can you please more specific and let me what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Had the same prob. Try

```
 [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile ProfileImage { get; set; }
```